# Search In OpenFile Dialog C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am using OpenFileDialog in C# to open files , What i would like to do is to make some restriction. I have set Text Files / .txt filter.

1- In Filename Textbox , when i press "a" it displays a downlist with all files(alph.dll, alchol.txt,alman.doc etc) starts with "a" regardless of what extension they have. I would like to only display .txt files in downlist (alchol.txt only).. Is it possible ?? How can i do this ??

Your help in this regard ill be highly appreciated..

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set the `DefaultExt property and Filter property` of the FileDailog

like this

```
fileDialog1.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
```

and

```
fileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt" ;
```